# Перезагрузка Asterisk из docker

Tags: centos, docker, asterisk

Использую docker-образ астериска dougbtv/asterisk14. Файлы настроек пробрасываю в контейнер с помощь опции -v (-v .../sip.conf:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf)  После изменения файла на хосте, в астериске контейнера пытаюсь перечитать эти настройки, но изменения не применяются. В связи  с этим вопрос: при создании докер-образа при пробросе файлов создается их копия, или используется один и тот же файл? И если первое, как сделать доступным изменения в контейнере без перезапуска его целиком?

**UPD:
Запуск контейнера:**

```
docker run --name=asterisk --net=host --restart=always -v /usr/share/restcomm/asterisk/sip.conf:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf -v /usr/share/restcomm/asterisk/extensions.ael:/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael -d -t dougbtv/asterisk14
```

**Вывод docker inspect**

```
[
    {
        "Id": "50ff2917df273d3ea62df41bc35fe45daeeee41a12c770420c8bd3c122354e13",
        "Created": "2017-03-08T16:43:26.811690072Z",
        "Path": "/bin/sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "asterisk -f"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 18277,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2017-03-08T16:43:27.145290714Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:896bf5cfc5a6b9d078d31a30e588918a064d814ea7a02a6bb9cb45b07b827298",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/50ff2917df273d3ea62df41bc35fe45daeeee41a12c770420c8bd3c122354e13/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/50ff2917df273d3ea62df41bc35fe45daeeee41a12c770420c8bd3c122354e13/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/50ff2917df273d3ea62df41bc35fe45daeeee41a12c770420c8bd3c122354e13/hosts",
        "LogPath": "",
        "Name": "/asterisk",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "devicemapper",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": [
                "/usr/share/restcomm/asterisk/sip.conf:/etc/asterisk/sip.conf",
                "/usr/share/restcomm/asterisk/extensions.ael:/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael"
            ],
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "journald",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "host",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "always",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "docker-runc",
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DiskQuota": 0,
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "devicemapper",
            "Data": {
                "DeviceId": "15",
                "DeviceName": "docker-253:0-13858-d8bf701e1bcdfb8ea373ec4d64c32cdf0467ed84b3ae58cf25a76cab02ee6449",
                "DeviceSize": "10737418240"
            }
        },
        "Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/usr/share/restcomm/asterisk/sip.conf",
                "Destination": "/etc/asterisk/sip.conf",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            },
            {
                "Source": "/usr/share/restcomm/asterisk/extensions.ael",
                "Destination": "/etc/asterisk/extensions.ael",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "<...>",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "Tty": true,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "build_date=2017-03-01"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "asterisk -f"
            ],
            "Image": "dougbtv/asterisk14",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "build-date": "20161214",
                "license": "GPLv2",
                "name": "CentOS Base Image",
                "vendor": "CentOS"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "83d7947e4ed2e34cbaa3774801ce10293d70f478b8393cdac0d571f7ba4fa0e5",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {},
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/default",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "",
            "Gateway": "",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "",
            "IPPrefixLen": 0,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "",
            "Networks": {
                "host": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "1cb1bae1b3959d439cdcc7938f2cefe664ea1e8e640b0ae40b4a7be0f03f9d39",
                    "EndpointID": "3557af97cd0b828bd06c33444bc27ca858f0e780d5e6d4124d24b34621d2c660",
                    "Gateway": "",
                    "IPAddress": "",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": ""
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Правка sip.conf и extensions.ael с помощью vim из контейнера и из хоста приводят к изменению только в одном варианте.

Comment: Используется один и тот же файл, проще всего представлять это, как симлинк. Видимо, либо вы не перезагрузили демон, либо он и при новых настройках работает так же.

Comment: @etki Изменил sip.conf внутри контейнера, на хосте изменений нет. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: Можете приложить вывод `docker inspect <container name/id>`, полную команду запуска и то, как вы редактируете файл?